# How to programatically build and compile another c# project from the current project

Tags: c#

Program A: output a c# function, and insert the function into a file (eg. Classifier.cs) in another c# project B. These steps have already been implemented.

I am wondering is there any way to programmatically build and compile the the c# project B inside project A. So I can click a button in project A, it will automatically insert the new function into project B, build, compile the project B. And finally launch the new project B.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of compilation assemblies for .NET that are now obsoletes.
For compilation, use Microsoft.Build.

First, Add this following references :

- Microsoft.Build
- Microsoft.Build.Engine

Secondly, import :

```
using Microsoft.Build.Evaluation;
```

And finally, write this code :

```
var configuration = "Release";
var projectDirectory = @"C:\blabla";
var collection = ProjectCollection.GlobalProjectCollection;
var project = collection.LoadProject($@"{projectDirectory}\MyProject.csproj");
project.SetProperty("Configuration", configuration);

project.Build();
```

Comment: collection.LoadProject give error "Microsoft.Build.Exceptions.InvalidProjectFileException: 'The tools version "14.0" is unrecognized. Available tools versions are "4.0".  C:\Users\User\Documents\Projects\practice\wpf\WPF-Samples-netframework\Graphics\2DTransforms\2DTransforms.csproj'"

Answer (score 1):

No need to execute a new process.  .NET gives us a way to invoke the C# compiler programatically. I find this technique works well:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dohollan/archive/2010/08/09/programmatically-invoke-the-c-compiler.aspx

Comment: This link is no longer good. It just goes to the top of the blog stack, which only goes back to 2020. I recommend replacing it with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/dotnet/csharp/compile-code-using-compiler. The edit queue is full, so I can't suggest that as an edit.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you're using Visual Studio you could just use run MSBuild against your ProjectB.csproj. That way you project should build identical to how it would build in Visual Studio.